# To customize a messagebox, should I hook the messagebox or use CreateWindowEx to create an imitation?

Tags: c++, performance, winapi, hook

I've been trying to create a `MessageBox` with changeable, readable text and customizable buttons, I think making a hook for it would probably be easy for this but I read at MSDN:

"Hooks tend to slow down the system because they increase the amount of processing the system must perform for each message. You should install a hook only when necessary, and remove it as soon as possible."

I'm wondering whether it's really worth it when I can just use `CreateWindowEx` to make an imitation `MessageBox` that does all I want. How much do hooks really slow the system down, is it worth it or should I be going with `CreateWindowEx` instead?

Comment: Add the hook before the call to `CreateWindowEx`, capture the creation of the message box and remove the hook after it's been created.

Comment: A single hook you install just temporarily in order to customize a standard `MessageBox` has zero slowliness effect.

Comment: May depend in how much customization you want to do. At a certain point, it's simpler to just DialogBox() on your own template that does what you want rather than shoe-horning MessageBox() into doing something it's not designed for. Keep in mind that MessageBox's controls and layout are implementation details, there's no guarantee they'll remain as they are on future versions of Windows.

Comment: `MessageBox` was not designed for customization. It is a convenience function that creates dialog boxes in a manner that changes from one version of Windows to another. If you want a custom dialog, then create a custom dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your target systems, have you considered using one of the new message boxes ([Task Dialogs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756938.aspx)) available starting with Windows Vista?

These allow you to customize the dialog layout of the box with custom buttons, etc. without requiring any hooks or custom windows (as in "create from scratch").

Otherwise I'd probably go with the hooks (you only need them to catch your box, so you could setup them before showing the box, and removing them once you've been successful).